# BoofCV / Java - Constructing Hessian matrix of an image with Gaussian convolution

Tags: java, image-processing, computer-vision, boofcv, hessian-matrix

I want to build a **Hessian matrix of a grayscale image** but I need to calculate the second order derivatives. I'm working with **BoofCV** and I found out a function that calculates the first order:

```
ImageGradient_Gaussian<ImageUInt8,ImageFloat32> gaussian1 = new ImageGradient_Gaussian<ImageUInt8,ImageFloat32>(sigma, -1, ImageUInt8.class, ImageFloat32.class);
gaussian1.process(grayscaleImage, derivX, derivY);
```

I'm using as an input parameter "sigma" (standard deviation).
Is there a function, or an other way, to calculate the second order derivatives using as input sigma and a grayscale image?

I'm open to other Java CV library suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like:

```
GImageDerivativeOps.sobel(grey, derivX, derivY, BorderType.EXTENDED);
GImageDerivativeOps.hessianSobel(derivX, derivY, derivXX, derivXY, derivYY, BorderType.EXTENDED);
```

grey can be ImageFloat32 or ImageUInt8
deriv can be ImageFloat32 or ImageSInt16

The latest SNAPSHOT has an example, but it should work on older versions too:

https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/blob/master/examples/src/boofcv/examples/imageprocessing/ExampleImageDerivative.java

Comment: I was using a Gaussian kernel for first order partial derivatives... So hessianThree() method worked just fine for me! Thanks again!